# Product of sums equal to sum of products

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Is

$(\sum_k x_k)(\sum_i y_i)(\sum_j z_j)(\sum_l a_l) = \sum_{kijl}x_ky_iz_ja_l$

with

$\sum_{kijl} = \sum_k\sum_i\sum_j\sum_l$?

Comment: Yes.(I had 10 more to go.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us prove of for two sums.

When you distribute the product over the left sum you get
$$
\left( \sum_i x_i\right) \left( \sum_j y_j\right)
= \sum_i \left( x_i  \sum_j y_j\right)
$$
and, when  you distribute on the second sum you get
$$
= \sum_i \left(  \sum_j x_i y_j\right)
$$
which is the result (you can drop the $(.)$s as the sum is associative).