# Sum of products equals product of sums

Tags: summation, real-numbers, products

Let $I_1,\dots,I_n$ be finite index sets and $a_i$ be real numbers. This might be a rather easy question, but I do not see how to prove that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_n)\in I_1\times\dots\times I_n} a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\dots a_{i_n} = \left(\sum_{i_1\in I_1} a_{i_1}\right) \dots\left(\sum_{i_n\in I_n} a_{i_n}\right)
\end{equation}
holds. The formula is also mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125323/how-to-apply-multinomial-theorem-here) as a generalized distributive law. It is heuristically clear to me why the formula holds, but I do not see how to come up with a proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try induction.

Comment: By distributivity of the product over a sum,$$\left(\sum_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_j a_j\right)=\sum_i\left(a_i\sum_j a_j\right)$$

and 

$$\sum_i\left(a_i\sum_j a_j\right)=\sum_i\sum_j a_i a_j$$

Comment: My mistake: This question was already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064686/product-of-sums-equal-to-sum-of-products) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158396/is-joining-split-sums-as-a-nested-sum-just-the-distributive-property-how-to-pro?).